# Making changes to object state from within a function

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, pass-by-reference

I have had to simplify some of my code to ask this question. However, in the below code does the fact that I am not declaring `x` as a reference type mean my change of decrementing will get "forgotten" once the function has exited?

The smartest way to fix this would be to declare `x` as `AnotherClass& x`?

```
void MyClass::myFunc(unordered_map<int, AnotherClass>* dictionary, int z, int y){

    AnotherClass x = dictionary->at(z);

    //Does this change on x get "forgotten" in terms of what dictionary stores
    //once myFunc() has finished, because x is not a reference/pointer type?
    x.changeSomething(y--);
}


class MyClass{
    public:

    private:
        myFunc(unordered_map<int, AnotherClass>* dictionary, int z);
        unordered_map<int, AnotherClass>* dictionary

};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct. `x` is a copy of an element of `dictionary`. You are applying changes to the copy, which is local to the function. You should see no effects in the caller side. You can either take a reference, or act directly on the result of the call to `at`:

```
dictionary->at(z).changeSomething(z--);
```

Note that this has nothing to do with the code being inside a function.

Comment: Just an extra question, if I wasn't modifying dictionary but I was creating a new AnotherClass object to insert in to dictionary- I wouldn't need to declare the new AnotherClass object as a reference type, it can just be AnotherClass new_obj?

Comment: @user997112 I'm not sure I understand the question, but maybe this will clarify things: 1) a reference has to refer to something. It is just an alias for an object. 2) when you put an object in a map, the map makes its own copy of that object. So you *can* give pass the map a reference to another object, but it makes no difference because the map will make a copy of the object it refers to.

Comment: I think you answered it anyway- I wouldnt be able to declare a new dictionary element of reference type because as you say, you need an existing element and I was asking about a new element going in to the dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

In languages like Java or C# when you write `Thing t = s;` you are actually creating an alias `t` that refer to the same object in memory than `s` refer to. In C++, however, values and aliases are strictly separated:

- `Thing t = s;` is about making a **copy** of `s`
- `Thing& t = s;` is about creating an alias referring to the same object than `s` (a reference)
- `Thing* t = &s;` is about creating an alias referring to the same object than `s` (a pointer)

The difference between references and pointers does not matter here, what matters is the difference between copies and aliases.

- Changes to a copy are local to that copy
- Changes to an object *via* an alias are local to that object, and visible through all *aliases* referring to that object

In term of your example:

```
// Fix 1: take dictionary by *reference* and not by *pointer*.
void MyClass::myFunc(std::unordered_map<int, AnotherClass>& dictionary, int z, int y){
    // Fix 2: dictionary.at(z) returns a "AnotherClass&"
    // that is an alias to the element held within the dictionary.
    // Make sure not to accidentally make a copy by using that "&"
    // for the type of x.
    AnotherClass& x = dictionary.at(z);

    // "x" is now a mere alias, the following call is thus applied
    // to the value associated to "z" within "dictionary".
    x.changeSomething(y--);
}
```

Note that you could write `dictionary.at(z).changeSomething(y--);` in this case; however there are several shortcomings:

- if `x` is reused more then once, naming it makes it clearer.
- in cases where the function/method invoked have side-effects, the number of calls is important and need be controlled.
- from a performance point of view, avoiding unnecessary computing the same thing over and over is always welcome... but don't get too hang up on performance ;)